# pyqt auto completion in a table

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qcompleter

I need auto completion in a table. So far, I could make it work that I get the same list for the entire table.

However, I need a dynamic list for each cell. How can I get update the list when I move to a new position in the cell?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class mainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.center_window = centerWindow(parent=self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.center_window)


class centerWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(centerWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        table = QTableWidget()
        table.setItemDelegate(TableItemCompleter())
        table.setRowCount(5)
        table.setColumnCount(1)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(table)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


class TableItemCompleter(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(TableItemCompleter, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, styleOption, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)

        completion_ls = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']

        autoComplete = QCompleter(completion_ls)
        editor.setCompleter(autoComplete)
        return editor


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        print('QApplication instance already exists: %s' % str(app))


    ex = mainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To make it more clear. Instead of having the `completion_ls` list in the `TableItemCompleter`, I'd like to add something like this:

```
table.setItem(row, column) #add my new auto completion list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QCompleter` can be established a model that uses as a source for the autocomplete, we could pass the `QModelIndex` model that provides the method `createEditor(self, parent, option, index)` through `index.model()` but the problem is that you can only take a column and is not what is desired.

Then we must do a conversion of the tablemodel to a listmodel, and then we must filter the repeated elements so that the completer shows unique elements, one way to do them is through proxies, classes that inherit from `QAbstractProxyModel`, the scheme is as follows:

```
TableModel ----> ReadTable2ListProxyModel ----> DuplicateFilterProxyModel
```

En la siguiente sección muestros las clases:

```
class ReadTable2ListProxyModel(QIdentityProxyModel):
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.sourceModel().rowCount() * self.sourceModel().columnCount()

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        if sourceIndex.isValid() and sourceIndex.column() == 0\
                and sourceIndex.row() < self.rowCount():
            r = sourceIndex.row()
            c = sourceIndex.column()
            row = sourceIndex.model().columnCount() * c + r
            return self.index(row, 0)
        return QModelIndex()

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        r = proxyIndex.row() / self.sourceModel().columnCount()
        c = proxyIndex.row() % self.sourceModel().columnCount()
        return self.sourceModel().index(r, c)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column)


class DuplicateFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def setSourceModel(self, model):
        model.dataChanged.connect(lambda: self.invalidate())
        QSortFilterProxyModel.setSourceModel(self, model)

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        value = self.sourceModel().index(row, self.filterKeyColumn())\
            .data(self.filterRole())
        if value is None:
            return False
        if row == 0:
            return True
        for i in reversed(range(0, row)):
            val = self.sourceModel().index(i, self.filterKeyColumn())\
                .data(self.filterRole())
            if val == value:
                return False
        return True
```

Then the conversion is established in the delegate:

```
class TableItemCompleter(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        completer = QCompleter(parent)

        proxy1 = ReadTable2ListProxyModel(parent)
        proxy2 = DuplicateFilterProxyModel(parent)
        proxy1.setSourceModel(index.model())
        proxy2.setSourceModel(proxy1)

        completer.setModel(proxy2)
        editor.setCompleter(completer)
        return editor
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48123219) you will find an example, and in the following image the operation is illustrated, in the first widget the table is observed, in the second the conversion to list and in the third the list eliminating duplicate elements.

[image]

---

If you want each item to have a list what can be done is to store the list in each item through a role that is not in use as `Qt.UserRole` through the `setData()` method, and in the delegate through the method `data()` of the `QModelIndex`:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import random

class TableItemCompleter(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        completion_ls = index.data(Qt.UserRole) # get list
        completer = QCompleter(completion_ls, parent)
        editor.setCompleter(completer)
        return editor

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        tv = QTableWidget(3, 4, self)
        lay.addWidget(tv)
        l = ["AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "BA", "BB", "BC"]
        for i in range(tv.rowCount()):
            for j in range(tv.columnCount()):
                it = QTableWidgetItem(f"{i},{j}")
                tv.setItem(i, j, it)
                it.setData(Qt.UserRole, random.sample(l, 3)) # set list
        tv.setItemDelegate(TableItemCompleter(tv))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But, this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. The source of my completion is not the table itself. It is another list. But the source list is different for every cell.

Comment: @StephanF. Ok, now I understand, and update my answer fulfilling your requirement :D

Comment: Perfect, that is what I needed. Please note, I had to remove the argument  in `it = QTableWidgetItem()` in order to make it work.

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: I'm using python2.