# Implementing QAbstractProxyModel methods

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qidentityproxymodel

I have a QSqlTableModel which has approximately this structure:

```
| ID |  Name  |
---------------
|  0 |  Xxxx  |
|  2 |  Yyyy  |
|  5 |  Zzzz  |
```

As you can see, IDs (which are unique) are sequential, but can be skipped; the available range is always from 0 to 1023. I need to create a table that fills the gaps up to the 1024 rows, without changing the source model layout. The final result will be something like this:

```
|  0 |  Xxxx  |
|    |        |
|  2 |  Yyyy  |
|    |        |
|    |        |
|  5 |  Zzzz  |
      ...
|1023|  Xyz   |
```

The "blank" items will not be editable, but the user will be able to use drag&drop to reorder (which will be implemented internally interfacing with the SQL model) and add/remove items, while always keeping the table size to 1024 rows.

I tried implementing QAbstractProxyModel, but I have some problems. For instance, the flags are not respected and *every* item is not editable, nor selectable. Even if I specifically return `ItemIsEnabled|ItemIsSelectable|ItemIsEditable`, nothing changes. Also, clicking on items gives strange results for header highlighting.

I suppose I'm doing something wrong with `mapToSource/mapFromSource`, but I'm not sure.

This is an example I made using QStandardItemModel instead of QSqlTableModel (the resulting behavior is the same) with 4 rows, and a Proxy showing 6 rows.

```
class BaseModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QStandardItemModel.__init__(self)
        for id, name in [(1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three'), (5, 'Five')]:
            idItem = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            idItem.setData(id, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            nameItem = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
            self.appendRow([idItem, nameItem])


class ProxyModel(QtCore.QAbstractProxyModel):
    def data(self, index, role):
        source = self.mapToSource(index)
        if source.isValid():
            return source.data(role)
        return None

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(section + 1)
        return QtCore.QAbstractProxyModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        return self.sourceModel().setData(self.mapToSource(index), value, role)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=None):
        res = self.sourceModel().match(self.sourceModel().index(0, 0), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, row, flags=QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
        if res:
            return res[0].sibling(res[0].row(), column)
        return self.createIndex(row, column)

    def parent(self, index):
        return self.sourceModel().index(index.row(), index.column()).parent()

    def flags(self, index):
        source = self.mapToSource(index)
        if source.isValid():
            return source.flags()
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return 6

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 2

    def mapToSource(self, index):
        res = self.sourceModel().match(self.sourceModel().index(0, 0), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, index.row(), flags=QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
        if res:
            return res[0].sibling(res[0].row(), index.column())
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def mapFromSource(self, index):
        if index.row() < 0:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        row = self.sourceModel().index(index.row(), 0).data()
        return self.createIndex(row, index.column())


class Win(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.model = BaseModel()
        self.proxy = ProxyModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        table.setModel(self.proxy)
        layout.addWidget(table)
```

Comment: From what I understand you want the table to show 1024 rows and fill in the missing rows, am I correct? If so, do you want the empty rows to be editable?

Comment: No, the empty rows will not be editable, but the model will be read/write in some way, since the user could change the order by internal drag/drop (causing them to change their ids) or "fill" the blank rows from an external source (by dropping from another table, via context menu, etc).

Comment: explain yourself better, let's say that one item is dragged from another table and released over an empty row, what should happen?

Comment: The table where the drag will start from will have items *without* the ID; the result will be that the dragged item[s] will be added to the source table, and an ID will be set for it/them, according to the row it/they will be dropped in; I used only one column in the example, there are actually more, and one of them is an UUID used as primary key across tables and references, which will never be shown but has to be in the model. The actual database structure is a bit more complicated, I simplified it since I didn't think it would matter.

Comment: I have posted an answer considering only your initial question, tell me if something is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to implement a `QAbstractProxyModel`, in this case it is sufficient to use a `QIdentityProxyModel`:

```
class ProxyModel(QtCore.QIdentityProxyModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(section + 1)
        return QtCore.QIdentityProxyModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.column() == 0:
            if not (0 <= int(value) < self.rowCount()) :
                return False
        return QtCore.QIdentityProxyModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 6

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column)

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        if sourceIndex.isValid()  and 0 <= sourceIndex.row() < self.rowCount():
            ix = self.sourceModel().index(sourceIndex.row(), 0)
            return self.index(int(ix.data()), sourceIndex.column())
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        res = self.sourceModel().match(self.sourceModel().index(0, 0), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, proxyIndex.row(), flags=QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
        if res:
            return res[0].sibling(res[0].row(), proxyIndex.column())
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()
```

Comment: Thanks. From your example I realized that the "only" big mistake I made was implementing `index()` by remapping to the source model (that's the reason of the odd behavior, I think). After correcting that, my class behaves as expected. I thought about using QIdentityProxyModel, but from the description it seemed that it wasn't suited for editing source model data too. Also, I might even need some filtering, but I suppose that I could use a QSortFilterProxyModel used on top of mine.. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @musicamante If you want a filtering it is not necessary to overwrite this proxy, create a QSortFilterProxyModel and pass it as a source to the initial proxy, in the following response there is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48123982/6622587

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, but I thought that I would use it "after" (hence the "on top of mine", sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly): SqlModel > MyProxy > FilterProxy. Since it will probably filter out "blank" rows, it should be better, or is there something I'm not considering?

Comment: @musicamante 
if you do not want to filter empty rows, overwrite the filterAcceptsRow method of QSortProxyModel to accept those rows.

Comment: It's ok to filter out empty rows, what I'm not sure of is if there's any difference I'd need to take into account if I use FilterProxy "before" or "after" my proxy.

Comment: @musicamante 
Yes it is difference, if you realize the transformations that you use are not commutative.